# Suggest filename / location in "Save As" dialog window (with different file types)

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to fill the "file name" but an own string.
I'm starting with a template file, I hit "save", and I get the "Save file as" dialogue window, in this window I would like to have a custom file name filled.
I don't want a specific "save button" on my Excel sheet, so I guess I'm mandatory to use the "Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave" event.
This is the code I have atm:

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)
    If SaveAsUI Then
        Dim suggestedFileName As String
        suggestedFileName = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1")
        With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogSaveAs)
            Application.EnableEvents = False
            .InitialFileName = suggestedFileName
            .FilterIndex = 2
            If .show Then
                ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=.SelectedItems(1), FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled
            End If
            Application.EnableEvents = True
        End With
        'Cancel true is necessary to avoid having 2 "save as" dialogue windows
        Cancel = True
    End If
End Sub
```

When I save the file nothing happened (as excepted) and when I save the file as I get the dialog window with my file_name proposition I want.
But it seems that with the code here above saves with the fixed extension of "xlsm", it's not taken from the combo box 'Save as type' at the bottom of the "Save as" window.
This is a major problem because beside XLSM I also use the "save as" function to export the sheet into a PDF file.

The thing I would like now is :

- how can you use the filetype selected from the combobox instead of "hard coded".
- how to set the file location; how / where can you specify this into the SaveAs function ?

I thought it would be easy, but surprisingly it isn't...

Comment: Why is that surprising? You explicitly write `FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled`in your code.

Comment: If you know the name and workbook path, why using a dialog? You can replace all `With ... End With` with `ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=suggestedFileName, FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled`. If you need to save it with other extension, of course you should change `xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled` with the appropriate format. Then, i suppose that `Cancel = True` is there only for testing reasons... I also suppose that `suggestedFileName` keeps also the path and workbook extension...

Comment: @Storax it's surprising because I thought I was "suggesting" a filename and file format, so I don't get the error because the user (in this case me) changed the file format.
It should save the file how I wanted it to be.

Comment: @FaneDuru , the cancel = true is to avoid the double "save dialog" window which is quite annoying.

Comment: No, it just detemines a filename. If you want to change the file format you have to explicitly add that to the code

Comment: What kind of combo box do you use? An ActiveX or a Form Control?

Comment: I'm not using any 'custom' combo box, just the standard one at the bottom of the "Save file as" dialog window.

Answer (score 0):

You could take the following function, modify as needed and add this to your code

```
Function FileFormatValue(fName As String) As Long

    Select Case LCase(Right(fName, Len(fName) - InStrRev(fName, ".", , 1)))
        Case "xls": FileFormatValue = 56
        Case "xlsx": FileFormatValue = 51
        Case "xlsm": FileFormatValue = 52
        Case "xlsb": FileFormatValue = 50
        ' add further cases as needed
        Case Else: FileFormatValue = 0
    End Select
    
End Function
```

Your code would look like that

```
    If .show Then
        ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=.SelectedItems(1), FileFormat:=FileFormatValue(.SelectedItems(1))
    End If
```

Comment: Thanks, how can you find these numbers ? Because I'm using the "save as" to generate a PDF-file too.
With my code now it saves a PDF, but it's in reality a XLSM, because I can't open it in Acrobat (and after the save the file extension is changed from "xlsm" to "pdf" in my title).

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/office/vba/api/excel.xlfileformat

Comment: And just to be sure: your code here is substracting the extension of the filename you enter in the "file name" textfield, right ?
Can't it be "substracted" from the combolist under this textfield ?

Comment: Yes, the code is retrieving the extension form the filename. No idea how one could it get from the combobox in the dialog.

Comment: Yes, right. Creating a PDF file is a different story

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.exportasfixedformat

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223031/discussion-between-smirnoff103-and-storax).

Comment: Sorry but please edit your question in such a way that it is clear what you want and where are you stuck. It seems that you want to export files to PDF. Although the dialogbox is the same that doesn't mean that the logic behind is the same.